# share an image from url in flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, web, web-applications

I'm trying to use share_plus package to allow users to share images on my web app flutter who comes in the shape of an url from my back server.
When trying to share with smartphones, share_plus only provides sharing the url on gmail, outlook and paypal, but doesn't consider it as an image.

Any idea how to shape this url so the sharing options on smartphones os considers it as an image?

here my code:

```
new IconButton(
   onPressed: () async {
      Share.share(Uri.parse(my_image_url).toString());
   },
),
```

i'm struggling because i can't download the files in a Web app..

Thanks for your time

Comment: Have a look at this [package](https://pub.dev/packages/share_everywhere)

Comment: thanks, but the problem is still the same, the web app considers it as a link and not an image :/

Comment: shape the image means? You're saying that image is not being detected in android/iOS but why are you in Flutter web?

Comment: When i try the Web app with a smartphone, either an iphone or android one, i will edit my post to make it clearer. I can't download the image on a web app so i'm trying to find a way to make the sharing options from the smartphone os to understand that i'm trying to share an image and not an url.

Comment: @fgrea have you found any solution?